# How can i upgrade Mac OS through shell scripting? is it possible?

Tags: macos, shell, scripting, operating-system, upgrade

i am trying to upgrade 100 macbook pro from 10.10.3 to 10.10.4. i have a software for sending shell script to control those mbp.
How can i upgrade Mac OS through shell scripting? is it possible?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited for apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Use the `softwareupdate` tool. You can use it to view available updates, install recommended, all available, or specified updates, and more. See the man page for details.